# Can I mass edit jenkins jobs by modifying the config.xml files?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have a lot of jobs in jenkins and we have decided to make some wide ranging changes to all of them which will be very tedious to change through the UI. It would be much easier to edit them using scripts on the jenkins master machine but I'm not sure how to get jenkins to recognize changes to the the config.xml that haven't come through the UI or another api.

Is there a way to get jenkins to refresh job configurations from disk? Or a better way of mass editing jobs?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Under the "Managr Hudson" option, there's a "Reload Configuration from Disk" item that will do what you want - re-reads the config.xml for projects while Hudson is running.  You can always restart Hudson to get the same effect.

Comment: Perfect, I never noticed that option.

Comment: I would go with gareth_bowles' answer, as using "reload configuration from disk" will throw a "Reloading..." msg and kind of "cut" all job progress users could be looking at.

Comment: "Reload Configuration from Disk" doesn't work for me, but restart does.

Answer (score 17):

Another way to mass edit jobs is to use the REST API; you can edit the job configurations manually and then use HTTP POST to commit them back to Hudson.  If you go to [Your Hudson URL]/job/[example job name]/api Hudson will display help information on using the API.

Comment: this should be the appropriate answer for this question.

Answer (score 5):

You should probably make use of this plugin 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin

Comment: Brilliant plugin (nevermind plugin's name is a bit confusing).

Answer (score 1):

You can use XSLT (templates) to automatically generate configuration xmls and configure via rest api. Use Jenkins to configure its own jobs