# Batch renaming of Hudson jobs

Tags: java, hudson

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031160/can-i-mass-edit-hudson-jobs-by-modifying-the-config-xml-files) talks about batch renaming jobs in Hudson, but it only mentions modifying the config.xml file.

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Administering+Hudson says you can rename jobs by just renaming the directories they are in.

In my Hudson setup, I have many jobs tied together, and also use the Nested Views plugin which records the name of jobs in the master config.xml file.

It seems like the proper way to mass rename jobs is to rename the directory, then edit the master config.xml file, then the config.xml files in each job's directory. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this looks right.

Make sure Hudson is offline or "preparing for shutdown" and no affected jobs are running. Then restart or reload jobs from disk. An absolute must is to backup your configuration beforehand. A good idea is to create a copy of your configuration and test your changes there.

Answer (score 2):

Directly editing config.xml files should work fine. Alternatively you may want to use Hudson's remote API.

Using the remote API, renaming a job would be a 2-step process:

1. Copy the job, using a POST to `http://my-hudson-server/createItem?name=newJobName&mode=copy&from=oldJobName`
2. Delete the old job, using a POST to `http://my-hudson-server/job/oldJobName/doDelete`

Take a look at `http://my-hudson-server/api` for more detailed info on how to use the remote API.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple copy lose the linkage between upstream & downstream jobs?

Comment: Copying a job keeps its downstream links intact. So if jobs B, C and D are triggered by job A, then they will also be triggered by the new job CopyOfA. But having re-read your question, I realise that you want to rename the whole graph of jobs, which would be quite tricky to do using the remote API. I have written a script to do something like this in the past, but it's probably simpler to just manually edit the config.xml files like you suggested.